# Merging all layers in the registry

Tags: vector, pyqgis, merge

I was wondering if there is a way to merge multiple layers. I actually would like to merge all layers in the registry programmatically, all of them are point layers and have the same fields.
I have thinking I might copy all features from all layers and paste them into a new vector layer... but I believe there should be an easier option. What do you think??
Would that be possible?

Answer (score 3):

you can call a process like the merge function programmatically in python:

```
import processing
processing.runalg('qgis:mergevectorlayers', layer1, layer2, savename)
```

Comment: Right, and do it in a for loop with layer1 always being the already merged layer.

Answer (score 1):

MMQGIS plugin have your merge funcion... other merge funcion can be found in Processing/gdal Processing/saga

but MMGIS works as you aspected

Comment: Thanks Luigi!! I know there are some tools that allow me to do that, the problems is how to do it programmatically. I'd need to include all layers in the registry (created in previous processes, in "memory" most of them), load those plugins and merge tools into my code and get the wanted layer... I don't know if that's possible, I will keep pushing

Answer (score 0):

I solved it today. You might understand how to activate each layers.

But here is what I did:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeView
from qgis.gui import QgisInterface
from qgis.core import QgsLayerTree
from qgis.core import QgsLayerTreeNode
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.gui import *
import processing
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
iface.layerTreeView().setCurrentLayer(None) #Deselect what u previously selected one
for child in root.children():
#print ("- group: " + child.name())
if child.name() == "산정천": #to check subgroups within test group
    for subChild in child.children():
        subChild.name()
        if subChild.name() == "기초지도":
            
            for lastChild in subChild.children():
                lastChild.name()
                for EndChild in lastChild.children():
                    if isinstance(lastChild, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
                        EndChild.name()
                        #print(EndChild.name())
                        if EndChild.name() == "A0010000":
                            
                            iface.layerTreeView().setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection )
                            iface.setActiveLayer(EndChild.layer())
List = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
print(List)
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers",
{'LAYERS':List,'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:5186'),
'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
iface.layerTreeView().setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection )
```

I made one for selecting every "A0010000" named layers in "산정천" root group
and processing merge at temporary output.
This is working more than 3.x version I guess (3.22 for me).
This is my first code from my life, so if you need explanation I would be glad to help you.