# How to take all active layers as input for an iterative algorithm?

Tags: qgis, algorithm, iteration

I have a whole list of different layers I want to do a iterative clipping algorithm on. (Batch processing is not an option as the 'iterate' button is gone.)

This is a follow up on my question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274537/iterating-clip-over-multiple-layers-using-qgis).

It's tedious having to make a new model every time I want to do this task. It'd be easier if there was a way to give an input of all active layers. I have no experience with pyqgis but it seems like a solid way to start if there is no easier way, but that's for another question.

My question, is there a way to take all active layers as an input for a iterative geoprocessing algorithm?

Comment: I hope my code gonna be your help
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/448040/216964